# How do I create this funky B shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I am trying to re-create this nice shape below:

[image: shape]

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way, but what I have currently is this:

[image: my attempt]

I basically have two triangles for the mountains and one rectangle. The probelm is, the angle of the triangles is too sharp, and secondly, I don't know how I can join them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how do you feel about tracing the original image and repairing any defects or artifacts manually? If your objective is to learn a new technique, disregard my question.

Comment: Use the Pen tool and draw it. Is that not an option?

Comment: I'm [watching a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTbzLTqTvCE) on how to properly trace. The guy [has this](https://imgur.com/a/YdjM5Us) at the top, but I don't have it on my Illustrator, any idea on how I can get that to show?

Comment: Found it, I had to go to Windows > Control to get it to show. Going to attempt tracing now, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image example you posted looks like a stock image, which has a watermark. I'm uncomfortable showing you how to copy the design, since it would be copyright infringement. It would be less risky to create your own design rather than copy this.

However, such shapes can easily be made with the pen tool, by drawing straight lines, and the corners can be easily rounded using the corner widgets in Illustrator CC.

Example:

[image]

Comment: OP is simply asking how to make the design, using technique, there's no copyright infringement. OP isn't asking how to illustrate this for a logo for a client, for example.

Answer (score 1):

First step I would take, would be to get the rough shape of the exterior rectangle. I'll use orange for contrast purposes:

[image]

Next, I'll make the two triangles. They're not equilateral, but I'll get the process started with the Star took and 3 points:

[image]

Now I'll align the bottom of it with the rectangle, and distort the top until it aligns with one of the mountains:

[image]

Duplicate the triangle by using cmd+c, cmd, shift+v to paste in place. Then, I'll distort this one, making sure it's still aligned with the larger triangle:

[image]

I'm going to increase the stroke, and move it out of the way so I can work more accurately:

[image]

Now I'll use the pen tool to find the right angle for the right part of the smaller triangle:

[image]

Then, I moved the new path onto my illustration in it's correct spot. I Unite it with the smaller triangle:

[image]

The rectangle is going to be our most important shape moving forward, so I'll copy it (com+c) before proceeding. I select the large triangle and the rectangle, and Minus Back:

[image]

I will Paste in Place the rectangle I copied earlier, select it and the triangle+path we made earlier, and Intersect them:

[image]

Going into Outline mode will help us now (com+y). I will add two anchor points on the bottom shape:

[image]

Now I can delete the anchor point that's in the way, and move the anchor point on the top shape into a more accurate spot:

Last step! I'll just use the Direct Selection tool and change the radius of the corners until the shape fits:
[image]

[image]

Now I can add a white shape to create the overlap, and complete the illustration:

[image]

Comment: Is it normal to add a shape for the overlap? It feels like a hack to me! I thought one would "cut the path short" if that makes sense, so you'll see whitespace behind. Is that doable?

Comment: Yep! You can add an anchor point at that spot, direct select it, and then cut the path there. Direct select one of the points, and drag it to your preferred location.